# How to store pictures effectively in a database?

Tags: mysql

I'm planning to store pictures in a database (MySQL 5.6.15, InnoDB) as MEDIUMBLOB and I'd like to know which table structure is more effective.

For every picture I'd store a checksum, and every time the checksum is checked first, to see if the picture needs updating. Considering the checksum will be accessed every time, but the picture may not be, does it make a difference (in performance) if I store them in a single table or two seperatre ones:

> | user_id | picture | picture_checksum |

or

> | user_id | picture |
>
> | user_id | picture_checksum |

(P.S.: I don't want to get into the *"file system vs database"* debate, it's pretty much settled i'll be using a database.)

Comment: If every picture has a checksum then I'd say it makes sense to store them in the same table.  As long as you specify the columns in your select statement, I don't see any reason it would affect performance.

Comment: I didn't see any reason to use 2 tables.

Comment: I agree one table would be fine, just don't select everything with your SELECT statement.

Comment: Although you're probably going to regret this in the future as your tables become too gigantic to replicate or back-up effectively, why are you using `MEDIUMBLOB` instead of the largest possible type? The [storage requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html) are virtually identical, but the limits are higher, where `LONGBLOB` can hold pretty much anything, even high-res images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single table is the way to go here as the data is intrinsically related and you don't have an X-to-many relationship.

Be careful not to load the image when doing simple queries. `SELECT *` is a bad idea when it results in slamming megabytes of data over your connection if you never use that data.

Instead, be as precise as possible:

```
SELECT picture_checksum FROM pictures WHERE user_id=?
```

As a note, you'll probably want to use something more robust and collision resistant like SHA1 than a simple checksum.

Comment: My main issue is, that I'm not too knowledgeable about how MySQL stores tables: even if I do a proper SELECT that doesn't return the picture, the DB server itself has to "read trough" the image data as well, since they're in one table - or so I thought.

Comment: MySQL can skip over data it doesn't need to read, it's not a big deal. If you ask for the data, though, it will be compelled to read it and send it to your client which is why you need to be specific about the columns you want when dealing with tables that have `BLOB` or `TEXT` columns in them. Try and benchmark it yourself by loading in ten thousand images as a test.